# Data constructor not in scope: Unrecognised pragma

Tags: ihp

After going through the website first project, I wanted to add some static pages, I checked the following [IHP - Recipes](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/recipes.html) for static pages . That's how I proceded:

In `web/Types.hs` I added the following:

```
data StaticController      
  = WelcomeAction        
  | AboutAction          
  deriving (Eq, Show, Data)
```

At `Web/Static/About.hs`:

```
module Web.View.Static.About where
import Web.View.Prelude 

data About = About

instance View About where
   html About = [hsx| ~some html here~ |]
```

At `Web/Controller/Static.hs`

```
module Web.Controller.Static where
import Web.Controller.Prelude
import Web.View.Static.Welcome
import Web.View.Static.About

instance Controller StaticController where
    action WelcomeAction = render WelcomeView
    action AboutAction   = render AboutView
                                       `
```

The error I getting is :

```
Web/Controller/Static.hs:8:35
Data constructor not in scope: AboutView
|
|     action AboutAction   = render AboutView
|

build/Generated/Types.hs:3:1
Unrecognised pragma
|
| {-# GHC_OPTIONS -Wno-unused-imports, -Wno-dodgy-imports, -Wno-unused-matches #-}module    Generated.Types where
| ^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the view in a data type named `About`. So to render it, you would call `render About`, not `render AboutView`.

I would recommend renaming `About` to `AboutView`, which fits the IHP conventions better :)

Comment: That was it, my bad..

Thanks Zachary